# Balanced BST vs Balanced Binary Tree: Complexity

Tags: binary-tree, binary-search-tree, complexity-theory, verify

I am determining the complexity of different operations on a balanced BST vs a balanced BT. I want to know if I have figured out the right complexities. The operations are as follows,

Finding the Smallest Element

This would be O(LogN)for a balanced BST and O(N) for a BT.

Creating a List of Elements in PreOrder

This would be O(N) for both since all nodes will be traversed.

Creating a List of Elements Smaller than Some Value v

This would be O(N) for both although implementation wise a balanced BST could be much faster using in-order traversal.

Removing all leaves from a tree

This would be O(N) for both, all nodes need to be traversed to find leaf nodes.

Are these conclusions correct?

Comment: What do you mean by "Creating a List of Elements in PreOrder"? Do you retrieve a sorted list of the elements or a list as they are in the tree?

Comment: PreOrder as in a preorder traversal of the tree where I retrieve an element, recur left, recur right. I think a preorder traversal would be the same for either tree.